# Threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am beginar in python script. I want read msaccess database records and write into XML file.
Access database table have more than 20000 records.

Now i am able to do but , it is taking 4 to 5 minutes. So i implement threading concept. But threading also taking more than 5 to 6 minutes. Because each thread open datasource reading records from tables and close datasource.

I don't know how to solve the problems.

## CODE:

```
class ConfigDataHandler(Thread):

  def __init__(self, dev):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.dev = dev

  def run(self):    
    db_source_path = r'D:\sampleDB.mdb'
    db_source = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
    db_source.ConnectionString = 'PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                                 DATA SOURCE=' +   db_source_path + ';'
    db_source.Open()

    query = """ SELECT * from table"""
    source_rs = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Recordset')
    source_rs.Open(query, db_source, 3, 1)

    while not source_rs.EOF :
        f_units.append(source_rs.fields("Name").Value))
        source_rs.MoveNext()
    source_rs.Close()
    db_source.Close() 

    out =  render(f_units)
    open("D:/test.xml", "w").write(out)

d_list = get_dev_list()
for d in d_list:       
  current = ConfigDataHandler(d)
  current.start()
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code snippet here?

Comment: Have you used a profiler to see where the time is being spent?  I'll bet that 80% of the time is in the ODBC connection to Jet.  Can you profile your program to gather some facts?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned please paste your code snippet. First - threads have a synchronisation overhead which is causing multi-threads to run slower.

Second - the msaccess/JET database is very slow and not really suited to multi-threaded use. You might like to consider SQL Server instead - SQL Server Express is free.

Third - it is probably the database slowing down the processing. What indexes do you have? What queries are you making? What does "explain" say?

Comment: +1: Threads don't make an I/O bound program "magically" go faster.

Comment: Thanks for posting your code. I can immediately see a few problems.

self.dev is not used. You probably want to use self.dev in a WHERE clause for the SQL query. It would be much faster not to reopen the database each time (self.db_source?) and not reopen the XML file each time. Also opening the same file in 'w' mode will erase its contents each time.

Answer (score 0):

1. Undo the threading stuff.
2. Run the [profiler](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) on the original unthreaded code.
3. Replace the AODB business with ordinary ODBC.
4. Run the new code through the profiler.
5. Post your results for further discussion.